# Get nickname on message Xmpp Openfire

Tags: jquery, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have installed openfire 4.0.1

And I am using php-openfire-restapi to do roster management.

So now whenever I am adding any new roster in any user at that time I am adding nickname of that user. But now whenever I am debugging messages on webend its displaying original jid rather then nickname.

The message structure what I am getting is like :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' ack='379966120'>
    <message xmlns="jabber:client" id="l3svJ-64" to="user_2977_0@192.168.1.63/414ri279lg" from="user_2259_846@192.168.1.63/Spark" type="chat">
        <body>
            dsfsdf
        </body>
        <thread>WMH881</thread>
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:event"><offline/><composing/></x>
    </message>
</body>
```

Now strophe js using one function which displaying user name in chat windo that's like :

```
/** Function: getNodeFromJid
 *  Get the node portion of a JID String.
 *
 *  Parameters:
 *    (String) jid - A JID.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *    A String containing the node.
 */
getNodeFromJid: function (jid)
{
    if (jid.indexOf("@") < 0) { return null; }
    return jid.split("@")[0];
},
```

which is just splitting name from Jid

> Ex: if my JId is user_2977_0@192.168.1.63 then it will return user name like : user_2977_0.

But I want to display nickname, So how to do that ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?